# Excel conditional formating column Table extend new row

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, formatting

I have a table for accounting records (50 or 100 monthly entries), in which the data is entered monthly. When the month closes, the table is copied to a new sheet with a different name, but in the original table ("TbJournal") the original sheet (named "journal") the lines with data are deleted, and only the header and line are kept. of totals. And new data begins to be inserted.

However, in several columns there are conditional formats, which consider the existing rows in the table. For example: `=$R$2:$R$103`.
When I delete the rows from the previous month's data, this reference decreases to (for example) `=$R$2:$R$1`.

Somewhere I saw that it seems like you can put `=TableName[@RowName]` as a reference,But it doesn't work. EXCEL converts this reference to RC format `=$R$2:$R$103`.

So, I need, every new month, to modify the "conditional formats" (which are 24, in different columns) again.
Is there a way to maintain the "conditional formats" in the table, applicable to all lines and new lines that are added?
Grateful!!

I would like to be able to keep the table without data, but with all the conditional formats for the columns, which would be maintained as new rows were added.

Comment: Check [Use the Name Manager in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-name-manager-in-excel-4d8c4c2b-9f7d-44e3-a3b4-9f61bd5c64e4). You can created a custom named range based on a column of your table. Something like `R_MyRange = TableName[Targetcolumn]`. Then in your formulas use `R_MyRange` reference instead of `TableName[Targetcolumn]`

Answer (score 1):

I agree it doesn't work to use table references in conditional formulas.

Let's say column A was always populated with a number of it was part of the table data. You could then have a conditional formula range of `R2:R` where you change your condition from something like `=R2>5` to `=AND(ISNUMBER($A2),R2>5)`

By not trying to apply a conditional format to just your table, instead applying it to the entire column and building "is it in the table?" logic into the conditional formula, deleting rows don't shrink the range the conditional formula applies to. When entire rows are deleted, since the ranges don't specify an ending row, the problem you're posting about is avoided.

There are other ways to apply this technique. For example, if data entry is added within a table called TableName you could have a defined name of "InputTableLastRow" with a value of `=1+ROWS(TableName)` and then your conditional formula could instead be something like `=AND(ROW()<=InputTableLastRow,R2>5)`